# Netty ChannelPipelinefactory getPipeline() input parameters

Tags: netty

I have a question about what type of input can be provided to the getPipeline()...

I want that method to return a different pipeline for different ip addresses , basically the pipeline is same but some of the resources used by some of the handlers per stage may be or may not be same given the client IP.
eg. I want to share a object which is input to a stage(handler) based on IP, same IP=same Object.

I want this to happen at getPipeline() itself, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ChannelPipelineFactory.getPipeline()` does not accept any parameters, you cannot do what you want to with `ChannelPipelineFactory`.

Instead, I'd recommend you to make `ChannelPipelineFactory.getPipeline()` return a new pipeline with a handler which sets up the pipeline.  That is, the channel will start with a pipeline with a single handler, and the single handler's `channelConnected()` could append the actual handlers to the pipeline and remove itself.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyChannelPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
        return Channels.pipeline(new MyChannelInitializer());
    }
}

public class MyChannelInitializer extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
    public void channelOpen(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent evt) {
        Channel ch = ctx.getChannel();
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.getPipeline();
        if (matchesA(ch.getRemoteAddress()) { // Protocol A
            p.addLast("A.decoder", new DecoderA());
            p.addLast("A.encoder", new EncoderA());
        } else { // Protocol B
            p.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(...));
            p.addLast("B.decoder", new DecoderB());
            p.addLast("B.encoder", new EncoderB());
        }
        p.addLast("commonLogic", new CommonLogicHandler());
        p.remove(this);
        ctx.sendUpstream(evt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious why getPipeline wouldn't be able to accept any arguments, if I remember factory method pattern properly, they almost always have some input arguments based on which they return a proper implementor of the interface in question.

Comment: Simply, it was a design mistake. :-)